# TypeError: elements.get is not a function error in firebase functions

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am getting the below `error log` when running a firebase function, i am trying to get documents and values inside `recentPosts` array field.

```
Error: Unknown error status: Error: Unknown error status: TypeError: elements.get is not a function
    at new HttpsError (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:90:19)
    at admin.firestore.collectionGroup.where.get.then.catch.error (/srv/lib/index.js:71:15)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)
```

***Class:***

```
class PostTable {
   public commentCount : number;

   public dateTime : number;

   public docId : string;

   public post : string;

   public userId : string;

   public userName : string;

   constructor(commentCount: number, dateTime: admin.firestore.Timestamp, docId: string, post : string, userId : string, userName : string) {

       this.commentCount = commentCount
       this.dateTime=  dateTime.toDate().getTime()
       this.docId=docId
       this.post=post
       this.userId=userId
       this.userName=userName
   }

}
```

***function:***

```
export const getPosts = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

   if (!context.auth) {
      // Throwing an HttpsError so that the client gets the error details.
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError('failed-precondition', 'The function must be called ' +
          'while authenticated.');
    }


    let responseCollection : PostTable[] = []

         admin.firestore().collectionGroup('recentPostColl').where('users', "array-contains",context.auth.token.name)
                                 .get()

         .then(collectionOfPosts => {

            if(!collectionOfPosts.empty)
            {

               collectionOfPosts.forEach(element => {

                  let collection : Map<String, Object>[] = element.get('recentPosts')

                  collection.forEach(elements => {

                     try {
                        const p : PostTable = new PostTable(elements.get('commentCount')as number, elements.get('dateTime') as admin.firestore.Timestamp
                        ,elements.get('docId') as string,elements.get('post') as string, elements.get('userId') as string, elements.get('userName') as string);

                        const stamp : admin.firestore.Timestamp = elements.get('dateTime') as admin.firestore.Timestamp

                        const date : Date = stamp.toDate()

                        if(date.getTime() > new Date(data.date).getTime())
                        {

                              responseCollection.push(p)
                        }
                     } catch (error) {
                        throw new functions.https.HttpsError(error, 'Constructor error');
                     }

                  });
               });

            }


   })

   .catch(error =>{
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError(error, 'code error');
   })

   return responseCollection


})
```

***Document:***

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `collectionOfPosts` is a [QuerySnapshot](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/1.3.x/QueryDocumentSnapshot) object.  You're using its [forEach](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/1.3.x/QuerySnapshot#forEach) method to iterate the [QueryDocumentSnapshot](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/1.3.x/QueryDocumentSnapshot.html) objects contained within it.  Then, you're using get() to grab a specific field out of that snapshot.  That field is going to be represented as plain JavaScript array type, since the field is an array.  It's not a strongly typed array - you should assume that all the field types are plain JavaScript types and not TypeScript collection types.  You can't simply cast a plain JavaScript types to a TypeScript collection types.

You'll need to provide a specific, safe assertion you can make about that field (assuming it contains exactly what you think) in JavaScript terms:

```
let collection : object[] = element.get('recentPosts')
```

You can then index into `collection` as if it was a normal array:

```
let item = collection[0]
```

or iterate it as you would any other JavaScript array.

The individual items will be `object` type, and you also deal with them as if they were plain old JavaScript objects.

If you want to deal with TypeScript collection types instead, you will have to write some code to convert all those JavaScript arrays and objects to their TypeScript collection type equivalents.

Comment: so assigning `const p : PostTable = collection[0] as PostTable` will get all the values in it assigned to the members in the class ?

Comment: It's not really going to "assign" any members.  A cast operation like this simply layers an existing object "shape" over top another object.  It's your responsibility to make sure all the names and types are matched appropriately.  If they happen to not match, you could have problems at runtime, so you need to be certain everything matches.  But this is actually unrelated to your original problem.

Comment: everything works fine untill i assign `let item = collection[0] as Map<string, object>` and use `item.get('dateTime')`, the error is same that item.get is not a function

Comment: Same problem. You can't just cast plain JavaScript objects to the special TypeScript collection types.  You have to use them as they exist, or manually convert them.

Comment: got it used `Object.keys()` and `Object.values `to get the values